# baud rate for serial communication in linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

By default what is the baud rate during serial communication. That is if a write a program where I do not mention any baud rate, then what baud rate will be taken into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on a POSIX system:

1. Open a port using [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html).
2. Pass the the file-descriptor from 1. to [`tcgetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetattr.html) to initialise a `struct termios`.
3. Pass a reference to the `struct termios` from 2. to [`cfgetispeed()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/cfsetispeed.html)/[`cfgetospeed()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/cfgetospeed.html#)to get the port's current inbound/outbound baud rate.

Example:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

[...]

struct termios t = {0};
speed_t baudrate_in = 0;
speed_t baudrate_out = 0;
int fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR);
if (-1 == fd)
{
  perror("open() failed");
  exit(1);
}

if (-1 == tcgetattr(fd, &t))
{
  perror("tcgetattr() failed");
  exit(1);
}

baudrate_in = cfgetispeed(&t);    
baudrate_out = cfgetospeed(&t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setserial to find out
http://linux.die.net/man/8/setserial